# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 window title bars for default app appear broken

Tags: 16.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

After updating from Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 to 16.04 most of the window title bars of the default application are appearing broken(appearing very large).
I used GUI update procedure(not from terminal).
Default application means like, file browser, Calculator, setting window etc.
**Note:** While updating, it asked me to whether replace the configuration file or keep the older one, I choose keep the older one.

[image: File Browser looks like this]

[image: Settings window looks like this]

Comment: I have a question for you. Which icon theme it was ? :)

Comment: Did you have third party repositories added?

Comment: @Anwar this was 'FS-icon-ubuntu-megypt-light', and thanks for asking me :). The problem resolved after changing to default icon. Maybe those icons have some compatibility issue with 16.04.

Comment: @xangua yes I guess I have some. Anyway, the problem was due to some third party icons. :)

Comment: @seeamkhan Glad to see Ubuntu guys are so quick in solving problem with just hints :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to some icon incompatibility. I was using 'Fs-icons-ubuntu-megypt' which was not compatible with Ubuntu 16.04. From the tweak tool, I changed the icons to default and the issue was resolved.